# CSS: What is the correct way to style all links within a single table?

Tags: html, css

**My intent is to style all anchor tags within a table in a particular way.**

The anchor tags may be contained within various containers inside the table, including:

- table cells
- divs
- paragraphs

**My initial attempt:**

```
.FooterTable a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
    color: blue;   
}
```

This is occurring within a CMS (DotNetNuke), so pretty much everything has a style specified in a CSS class somewhere. However, I believe my CSS Class above should take effect.

**Here's my markup:**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="FooterTable">
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" align="center">
            <a href="http://www.test.com/pages/45_contact_us.cfm">Our Company</a>
        </td>
        <td width="19%" align="center">
            <a href="http://www.test.com/pages/6_test_test_test_test.cfm">Need Help?</a>
        </td>
        <td width="37%" align="center">
            <a href="http://www.test.com/pages/187_test_test.cfm">Shop</a>
        </td>
        <td width="21%" align="center">
            <a href="http://www.test.com/pages/42_test_test.cfm">Partners</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Current Behavior**

All text on the site is specified to be some sort of gray. That gray color is simply not being overridden with the above CSS Class.

What is the correct way to set the style of all links within a table, such as this?

Comment: I have no idea about dotNetNuke, but if you put that code at the very bottom of your HTML head and it still doesn't override, then chances are that they have it done after dom load, or they could be including  bits and pieces of styling all over the portal.

Comment: Exactly where is the gray color coming from? Can you show the code for that? It may be a specifity problem. Try to add the !important declaration and see if it overwrites the grey color. If it does than you have rule clash. The class selector has a lower specifity that the ID selector, so it maybe that somewhere in the code, grey color is specified by using an id selector. Or if you have inlines styles set, either dynamically, it may override the class rules. For a more powerfull rule, try table.FooterTable>tr>td>a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the correct idea, though you do need to make sure that `.FooterTable` precedes *each* `a`, as each comma separates full selectors.

Ideally, you could go with the simple:

```
.FooterTable a, .FooterTable a:hover {
    color: blue;   
}
```

But, you seem to be running into a [CSS selector specificity/precedence problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434800/why-is-this-invulnerable-to-styling/4435072#4435072).  Read that answer for more details, but basically, existing CSS rules being applied may "more specific" and therefore take precedence over your fairly simply `.FooterTable a:link` rule.

To verify this, I isolated just the HTML/CSS from this question into a sample page, and the blue color in the CSS rule in fact does apply to the links.

To fix this problem, you have two options:

1. Ideally, global CSS rules should not be overly specific.  If you can fix them to be less specific, you will be better all around.
2. If you can only *add* CSS rules, not take away from those already applied elsewhere, you will need to be *more specific*.  See my answer and other answers on StackOverflow for details on how selector precedence works.

Comment: @Blender - good point.  I was just trying to illustrate the principle of not being overly specific, but since browsers by default already may be more specific on `a:hover`, that would be necessary.

Comment: I fixed my CSS as you mentioned, then I used Firebug's "see which styles are active from where" feature to help identify any remaining issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case your CSS is overridden by the CMS's CSS, you can make it `!important`:

```
.FooterTable > tr > td > a:link,
.FooterTable > tr > td > a:visited,
.FooterTable > tr > td > a:hover,
.FooterTable > tr > td > a:active
{
    color: blue;   
}
```

You have to write out `.FooterTable` each time, as CSS isn't that dynamic.

Comment: Please don't do this - this is an extension of the [mess you are in in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967765/css-what-is-the-correct-way-to-style-all-links-within-a-single-table/5967824#5967824).  If you do, you will not be able to change the color of any links inside `.FooterTable`, even on a `style` attribute, without using `!important` again.

Comment: Without any more code, I can't say much else. If the OP's CSS is being inserted into the top of the page, then the CMS is overriding it. If not, then not.

Comment: It has more to do with selector specificity than which comes first, unless it's the *exact same selector*.  I've had so many other developers come to me to help fix CSS saying "!important isn't even working!" that I've stopped using it unless it's a last resort - though it fixes certain instances, for a developer who doesn't understand what it's actually doing, it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: Okay, then I'll be quite specific. See my edit (to come in a few seconds).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that selector isn't doing what you want it to. Commas separate *entirely independent selectors*. Which means you're targeting four different groups of elements:

1. `.FooterTable a:link` — All `a` elements in their normal, un-hovered, un-visited state that are descendants of any element with a class of `FooterTable`
2. `a:visited` — All `a` elements on the page that have been visited
3. `a:hover` — All `a` elements on the page that are being hovered

...and so on. You'll need to duplicate the `.FooterTable` part in each comma-separated selector.

The next problem sounds like a specificity problem. If you told all `.FooterTable a:link` elements to have a color of blue, then my guess is you have a more-specific rule somewhere else that tells those links to be a different color. We'll probably need to see more CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS looks correct. If it is not working then it could be overridden by a later style or it could be ignored because of another style or a style marked important.

You could use something like FireBug to find out which style is being used.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that another selector has a higher specificity than yours. If you have firefox and firebug installed, you can easily see what selector is being used and use that information to modify yours.

Apart from that, `.FooterTable a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active` is equal to:

```
.FooterTable a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active
```

so `.FooterTable` does not apply to the last 3 selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
.FooterTable a:link, .FooterTable a:visited, .FooterTable a:hover, .FooterTable a:active
{
    color: blue;   
}
```

if that does not work you may need to add TD