# how to apply css on only one class?

Tags: css

css

```
#inchannel li{
            width:179px;
            height:40px;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size:17px;
            color:#999999;
            background:url(img/green.png) no-repeat 8% 50%,url(img/back_line.png);

        }

        .ichn0{
            width:179px;
            height:123px;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size:17px;
            color:#999999;
            background:url(img/green.png) no-repeat 8% 18%,url(img/log_in_body.png),url(img/invite_button.png) no-repeat 60% 60%;

        }
```

html

```
<ul id="accordion">

<li>
    <a href="#" class="item category" rel="category"></a>
    <ul id="inchannel">
    <li class="ichn0"><img src="facebook/41403_1434825607_37944358_q.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="facebook/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="facebook/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

I want to apply css on only one class but it isn't applied to one class it seems like inchannel css covers all.
can any body tell me how to apply css on only one class?
Any thought?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "one class"...

Comment: use `!important` in the `ichn0` css  declration. If I understood what you need right.

Comment: can you show me how to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use higher specificity

```
#inchannel li.ichn0{
        width:179px;
        height:123px;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-size:17px;
        color:#999999;
        background:url(img/green.png) no-repeat 8% 18%,url(img/log_in_body.png),url(img/invite_button.png) no-repeat 60% 60%;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#inchannel li` has much more [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) tham the class .ichno.

There are several ways to combat this.

- Add !important to the properties of .ichn0

This is bad practice because you can overwrite user stylesheets like this, which are used for things like screen readers, etc.

- Add an ID to the first li.

This is OK, but not the way I'd go about it, personally.

- #inchannel:first-child

This is how I would go about it. In my eyes this is easiest to maintain across multiple pages.

- Add a class per Damen's answer.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this approach, either. I'm just a sucker for :psuedo selectors.

Answer (score 0):

- `#inchannel li` — Applies to all `li` elements inside the `#inchannel` element (all of them, in your case.
- `.ichn0` — Applies to `li` elements with `ichn0` class, regardless of what element they are inside.  There is only one of these.

The reason why the first is taking precedent over the `.ichn0` CSS is because of [CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330451/143295).  The `#inchannel li` selector is more specific and therefore overrides the less-specific `.ichn0` settings.

Changein `.ichn0` to `#inchannel li.ichn0` should fix your problem.